# Pergunta e resposta com if e else em Java

Tags: java, if, else

Não importa o que respondo, tanto "Sim" como "sim" só mostra o `ELSE`. Onde estou errando?

```
package saudacao;
import java.util.*;
public class Saudacao {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Ola, bom dia, voce esta bem hoje?");
        Scanner sdc_recebe = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sdc_armazena = sdc_recebe.nextLine();
        if (sdc_armazena == "Sim") {
            System.out.println("Que bom!!!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Que pena!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Você está escrevendo "Sim" ou "sim"?

Comment: nao importa, tanto Sim ou sim so exibe ELSE

Comment: Oi, fye, agradeça votando positivamente e se for o caso coloque esse tipo de obsevações como um comentário em vez de no corpo da pergunta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a função [`String.html#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), o operador [`==`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) é usado para comparar referências.

Veja a diferença:

```
String a = new String("foo");
String b = new String("foo");

System.out.println(a == b);      // False
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // True
```

O teu código pode ficar assim:

```
import java.util.*;

class Saudacao 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Ola, bom dia, voce esta bem hoje?");

        Scanner sdc_recebe = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sdc_armazena = sdc_recebe.nextLine();

        if (sdc_armazena.equals("Sim")) 
        {
           System.out.println("Que bom!!!");
        } 
        else 
        {
           System.out.println("Que pena!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/ua7rpe)</kbd>

Para comparar sem diferenciar letras minúsculas e maiúsculas, use a função [`String.html#equalsIgnoreCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-):

```
if (sdc_armazena.equalsIgnoreCase("Sim")) // Sim, sIM, SIM, sim...
{
   System.out.println("Que bom!!!");
} 
else 
{
   System.out.println("Que pena!!!");
}
```

Para comparar inteiros, `String.html#equals` também pode ser usado:

```
Integer I = 10;

if (I.equals(10))
{
   System.out.println("Igual!");
}
else
{
   System.out.println("Valores diferentes!");
}
```

Comment: no caso utilizado mais para INT que seria o == ?

Comment: isso, como se 1 e igual a 1 XD

Answer (score 4):

Poderia ser assim:

```
System.out.println("Ola, bom dia, voce esta bem hoje?");
Scanner sdc_recebe = new Scanner(System.in);
String sdc_armazena = sdc_recebe.nextLine();
if ("sim".equals(sdc_armazena.toLowerCase()) ||
    "aham".equals(sdc_armazena.toLowerCase())) {
     System.out.println("Que bom!!!");
} else {
     System.out.println("Que pena!!!");
}
```

Se não escrever nada, também não dá erro só vai direto pro `else`.

Comment: obrigado a todos, funcionou perfeitamente, para eu adicionar opcoes de resposta positivas que seria o OR eu teria que fazer outros IFs? ou posso por junto?

Comment: @fyeflourigh, eu não entendi bem ? como ?

Comment: eu quero poder responder "Sim" OR "sim" OR "Aham" ou seja, quero por mais respostas positivas que o usuario pode responder

Comment: Pronto usando toLowerCase() no sdc_armazena e comparado com "sim" em minusculo qualquer jeito que você digitar sendo sim ou Sim ou sIm ou etc vai passar! @fyeflourigh e utilize || sendo OR aham ou yes ou sim etc!!! editei a questão

Comment: ata, este e perfeito, isso ja tirou metade do trabalho, mas o que eu procuro mesmo e algo assim como no link a seguir, mas isso e em ALG e no caso queria a mesma coisa em JAVA http://likb.in/view/77526fab

Comment: Ok! entendi, em Java é assim que faz... como na minha resposta! Tem mais alguma dúvida? @fyeflourigh

Comment: muito obrigado, entao no caso o OU e o pipe duplo || sou muito grato mesmo, boa noite

Comment: Isso @fyeflourigh !!! em java || é OR ou OU